# .ParseExact unable to format a string based on an array of formats

Tags: c#

I would like to format a string based on a list of possible input formats. So for the string "2010/02/20" I would expect it to pass the first format in arr which is yyyy/MM/dd and be formatted using the first format in arr.

When I pass "20/02/2010" as strDate , it should be formatted using the second format in arr. But I got string was not recognized as valid date time.

```
           string strDate = "2010/02/20";
           //string strDate = "20/02/2010";
           string[] arr = { "yyyy/MM/dd, dd/MM/yyyy"};
           DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, arr, new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your `arr` wrong. Currently, you only have one valid format which is

```
yyyy/MM/dd, dd/MM/yyyy
```

So a valid date must literally have the following format (all 22 characters of it)

```
"2020/02/20, 02/20/2020"
```

To have two values in your array, define it as follows

```
var arr = new string[]{"yyyy/MM/dd", "dd/MM/yyyy"};
```